# Property of the norm of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to show that $ ‖ A^{2^k} ‖_2 = ‖ A ‖^{2^k}_2$ for a symmetric matrix $A$. I tried to go by induction and I was able to prove that $‖ A^{2} ‖_2 = ‖ A ‖^{2}_2.$ How to prove this for arbitrary $k$?

For $k=1$: 
$$\leq: \| A^2 \| \leq \| A \| \| A \| = \| A \|^2$$ by submultiplicativity.

$$ \geq: \| Ax\|^2 = ( Ax, Ax ) = x^TA^TAx = x^TA^TA^Tx = ( A^2 x, x ) \leq \|A^2x\| \|x\| \leq \|A^2 \| \|x \|^2.$$

Comment: Please show your try for $k=1$. Maybe the approach can be generalized. Thanks

Comment: @dxdydz If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^m$ is an eigenvalue of  $A^m$... The result should hold for any power of $A$, I don't see a point in proving for $2^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate "$\geq$" is clear by the definition of the operator norm similar as in the case $k = 1$, which was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3562470/529121). We show "$\leq$". Note that $\|A\|^{2^{k + 1}} = (\|A\|^{2^k})^2 = \|A^{2^k}\|^2$ is true by the induction hypothesis. The claim now follows from

$$\|A^{2^k} x \|^2 = \langle A^{2^k} x, A^{2^k}x \rangle = \langle A^{2^{k + 1}} x, x \rangle \leq \|A^{2^{k + 1}}x \| \|x \| \leq \|A^{2^{k + 1}} \| \|x \|^2. $$

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is symmetric, then $\lVert A \rVert_2 = \max_{i=1,...,n} |\lambda_i|.$
We can diagonalise $A = QDQ^T$ and see
$$ A^k = Q D^k Q^T, $$
so
$$\lVert A^k \rVert_2 = \max_{i=1,...,n} |\lambda_i^k| = \lVert A \rVert_2^k.$$